# I cloned the project with git. And now the error "Cannot find 'NewsTableViewController' in scope" appears

Tags: xcode, ios15, xcode13

I cloned the project with git.
And now the error "Cannot find 'NewsTableViewController' in scope" appears

I saw that there is no Target membership in the file attribute inspector with the error. So I don't understand how I can add it there - dragging and dropping didn't help.
[Target membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNvlb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sooo...I did it

1. Add missing files (folders/folders with files) to the project by dragging and dropping
2. In the window that appears, select the item with "groups", not "folders". Make sure that "Copy items if needed" is checked